# Outlook changes timestamp of a *.pst file not listed in its profile

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

I have an Outlook 2010 profile that has only one Exchange account and the associated *.ost file.  It has no *.pst file open (I checked by viewing the "Folders" navigation pane.

Yet every time I open Outlook and close it, a *.pst file in a different folder updates its timestamp.  This makes things very confusing as I'm not sure whether it has changed from the last time I took a snapshot of that *.pst file as a zip file.  These files are huge, so I am forced to decide whether to take another snapshot.  Not a good thing if the last snapshot is meant to be an authoritative "freezing" of the *.pst file.

**What might cause Outlook to change the timestamp of a file when it is not listed in the profile's "Data file"?**

INVESTIGATIONS DONE:

Someone suggested that Outlook might go through all Data Files in all its profiles and update the timestamp whenever it opens.  However, I have only one profile.

I renamed the *.pst file that was not part of the profile (yet whose timestamp was being updated by Outlook).  It stopped being updated by Outlook, and Outlook did not complain about a missing data file (it shouldn't, since it isn't associated with the profile).  This is not a practical solution though.  My filenames are chosen to fulfill certain informational functions.  Also, on other machines, I have more profiles, each with more data files.  The real solution is to find a way to make Outlook not update the timestamps of files not associated with the profile that is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your sharing.

Will this issue be reproduced if you move these .pst files to other folders? I did some research about your issue and got some similar threads. Some users mentions that when using Outlook desktop client, Outlook might automatically index related location for Outlook search feature which might cause issues like this. So, please try to move these pst files to other locations which is not in the index range and see if the issue has any difference.

Reference link:https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/outlook-changing-timestamp-on-all-my-pst-files-on-close.3345580/

**Addendum by author of the question**

Based on the above, I close a *.pst file in Outlook, quit Outlook, renamed the *.pst file, and reopened Outlook.  The renamed *.pst file's timestamp was not affected by opening Outlook, which is what I want.  However, I also want the *.pst file to keep its original name.  So I closed Outlook, renamed the *.pst file back to its original name, then opened & closed Outlook.  The *.pst file's timestamp was unaffected, which is the desired outcome.  *Thanks!*